# Is terribly used correctly here?

Tags: adverb-placement

- My English skills suck terribly.
- My English skills terribly suck.

Is the adverb **terribly** properly used in the above sentences? On top of it, can I ask what difference is there?

Thank you.

Comment: What is idiomatic would really depend on the full sentence, so don't jump to any conclusions based on a single example sentence.  Your sentence is quite different from, say, *The gardener [slowly moved|moved slowly] from plant to plant.* and either position is OK there. But      *She sings terribly* is idiomatic and *She terribly sings* is not.  *The dog badly needs a bath* and *The dog needs a bath badly* are both OK.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you very much for the sincere example sentences.:) Then, what do you think about the sentences I asked about?

Comment: *My skills of English terribly sucks*  imitates the fact it expresses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "terribly". The word "suck" already presupposes that they are terrible. "Suck terribly" would be a [pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) (basically, you are saying the same thing twice).

So, use either

> My English skills suck.

or

> My English skills are terrible (or nonexistent).

If this is a question about how to place an adverb beside a verb, in English, it's better to place it after the verb.

Comment: @SmartHumanism You can "accept" the answer if it has helped you. Accepting an answer will give you +5 reputation, and +15 reputation to the user whose answer you've accepted.

Comment: Yes, I was going to do it of course.:) But may I ask you some more about that? What you mean in the answer is that the sentences sound weird and wrong or that they are not good enough to be neat?

Comment: @SmartHumanism The sentence "My English skills suck terribly" is grammatically correct. But from the point of view of meaning, as I explained, you used a double portion of the meaning "be bad". Both "suck" and "terrible" have a meaning of "be bad". You don't need to use that twice. So the sentence is weird _semantically_ (from the point of view of meaning).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I think I have got the point.:) But I would like you ask more if I am not bothering you too much. I am not a native English speaker and I would like to know whether also many average native English speakers make the same mistakes I did. Would native English speakers feel something was wrong to some degree if I said those sentences in daily life? Or would only some educated people perceive those sentences as wrong?

Comment: @SmartHumanism This particular case of "Something sucks terrible" is also a mistake that a native speaker could have made. People make mistakes in their native languages all the time.